# Why the Javascript not working after changePage

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

When I changed the page, the javascript did not execute.

index.html

```
$("#login").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault(); 
$.mobile.changePage('main.html', {
    reverse : false,
    changeHash : false,
    allowSamePageTransition : true,
    reloadPage:true,
    transition: "flow"
});
});
```

main.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("Test");
    });
</script>
```

The above javascript in main.html does not execute upon page change; can anyone explain why this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because change page will cause reload of pages and JQM is not getting the head section of recently loaded page in the DOM so any scripts in the `<head>` of the document will not be included.

Hence, you can put all of your JS into an external file and include it on each HTML page of the site that you required.

You can also place your JavaScript code inside the `data-role="page"` element and you JS will be included.